# Setiing Institute Logo

Tags: beamer, presentations

How to place the logo in first page below my institute name and say in anywhere for knowledge. And also in every slides can i have my university name CUHP too (Hope i am clear on this)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
    \usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
    \setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
    \setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=green,bg=blue}
    \makeatletter
    \setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{3pt}
    \makeatother
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{float}
    
    
    
        \author{Anshul Sharma}
    \title{Symmetry in Quantum Mechanics}
    \institute {CENTRAL UNIVERSITY OF HIMACHAL PRADESH}
    \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{"../../../../../MSc. Days/4th Sem/PROJECT/MY NEW TASK/All latex written part/ALL SUBPARTS INSIDE/classical part/CUHP LOGO"}
    }
    
    \begin{document}
    
        \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Contents}
    \begin{itemize}\huge
        \item  Aim
        \item Objectives
        \item Apparatus
        \item Theory
        \item Experimental Setup
        \item Observations
        \item Results
        
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: The usual approach is to place the logo next to a minipage containing \maketitle and align the two using \raisebox.

Comment: @JohnKormylo can you re modify your answer by an example with the code what you mean as i am unable to catch the idea of yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the first frame code as under-- this will give you a picture graphic on the right side of your university title -- you can shift the position by experimenting with `(x,y)` values in `(5,0.6)`  -- in place of the graphic you can use your own

[image]

```
     \begin{frame}[plain]
                    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                \node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page.center)+(5,0.6)$){\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth, scale=0.1]{example-image}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \maketitle
    \end{frame}
```

Comment: can you help me with one more thing of how to add table of contents in beamer and it shows also nicely.

Comment: you may like to start a new question

Comment: here is the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554395/bibliography-in-beamer-and-table-of-contents

Answer (score 1):

I see from your MWE that `\maketitle` fills the whole frame, so instead I created the macro `\university` just to format the `\institute` as a line of text.  Without the overlap, the `\titlegraphic` starts running into the `\title` (bad `\maketitle` design).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
    \usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
    \setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
    \setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=green,bg=blue}
    \makeatletter
    \setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{3pt}
    \makeatother
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{float}
    
    \newcommand{\university}{CENTRAL UNIVERSITY OF HIMACHAL PRADESH \hfil
      \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\ht\strutbox-0.5\dp\strutbox-0.5\height}[0pt][0pt]% align centers and overlap
        {\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}}}
    
    
    
        \author{Anshul Sharma}
    \title{Symmetry in Quantum Mechanics}
    \institute {\university}
    \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
        \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Contents}
    \begin{itemize}\huge
        \item  Aim
        \item Objectives
        \item Apparatus
        \item Theory
        \item Experimental Setup
        \item Observations
        \item Results
        
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image: demo]