# Bibliography In beamer and Table of Contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, bibliographies, presentations

When i am running the code and generating pdf (from tools to commands to biber in Texstudio), the references page is not giving numeric numbering to the references, instead a small box if forming.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=green,bg=blue}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{3pt}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


    \author{Anshul Sharma}
\title{Symmetry in Quantum Mechanics}
\institute {CENTRAL UNIVERSITY OF HIMACHAL PRADESH}
\begin{document}
      \begin{frame}[plain]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page.center)+(-2,-2)$){\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, scale=0.1]{"CUHP LOGO"}
    }
        ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\vspace{-5cm}
\frametitle{Symmetries in Classical Physics}
Hi\cite{Cosmic} Bye\cite{PeriodicPotential}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\vspace{-5cm}
    \frametitle{Translation Symmetry}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\vspace{-5cm}
    \frametitle{Rotational Symmetry}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\vspace{-5cm}
    \frametitle{Degeneracy}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\vspace{-5cm}
    \frametitle{Parity}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\vspace{-5cm}
    \frametitle{Time Reversal Symmetry}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\vspace{-5cm}
    \frametitle{Symmetries in Dirac Equation}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Also how to add table of content in the beamer. Do i need to add section/subsection command for generating pdf or the frame title will do its job.

My bib File

```
@misc{goldstein2002classical,
  title={Classical mechanics},
  author={Goldstein, Herbert and Poole, Charles and Safko, John},
  year={2002},
  publisher={American Association of Physics Teachers}
}
@misc{zettili2003quantum,
    title={Quantum mechanics: concepts and applications},
    author={Zettili, Nouredine},
    year={2003},
    publisher={American Association of Physics Teachers}
}
@book{griffiths2018introduction,
    title={Introduction to quantum mechanics},
    author={Griffiths, David J and Schroeter, Darrell F},
    year={2018},
    publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}
@book{chaichian1997symmetries,
    title={Symmetries in Quantum Mechanics: From Angular Momentum to Supersymmetry (PBK)},
    author={Chaichian, M. and Hagedorn, R.},
    isbn={9780750304085},
    lccn={97048375},
    series={Graduate Student Series in Physics},
    url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=pEhjQgAACAAJ},
    year={1997},
    publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
@article{article,
author = {Vaccaro, Joan},
year = {2015},
month = {02},
pages = {},
title = {Quantum asymmetry between time and space},
volume = {472},
journal = {Proceedings of the Royal Society A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Science},
doi = {10.1098/rspa.2015.0670}
}
@book{sakurai2014modern,
  title={Modern quantum mechanics},
  author={Sakurai, Jun John and Napolitano, Jim and others},
  volume={185},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Pearson Harlow}
}
@MISC{Pinterest,
    author = {{Google images}},
    title = {Noether Theorem},
    year = {2020},
    note = {[Online; accessed May 7, 2020]},
    url = {https://www.pinterest.es/pin/322851867018550297/?amp_client_id=CLIENT_ID(_)&mweb_unauth_id=&from_amp_pin_page=true}
}
@MISC{Cosmic,
    author = {{Google images}},
    title = {Beta decay},
    year = {2020},
    note = {[Online; accessed May 13, 2020]},
    url = {http://cosmic-horizons.blogspot.com/2014/04/the-greatest-experiment-youve-never.html}
}
@MISC{PeriodicPotential,
    author = {{PDF}},
    title = {Periodic Poetntial},
    year = {2020},
    note = {[Online; accessed May25 , 2020]},
    url = {http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~eandrei/chengdu/reading/Energy_Bands.pdf}
}
@MISC{Energy,
    author = {{Google images}},
    title = {Energy Degenracy lifting up},
    year = {2020},
    note = {[Online; accessed May 25, 2020]},
    url = {https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixmAe.png}
}
@book{boas2006mathematical,
  title={Mathematical methods in the physical sciences},
  author={Boas, Mary L},
  year={2006},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}
@book{schwabl2012advanced,
  title={Advanced quantum mechanics},
  author={Schwabl, Franz},
  year={2012},
  publisher={World Publishing Corporation}
}
@article{article,
author = {Jugdutt, B. and Marsiglio, F.},
year = {2012},
month = {11},
pages = {},
title = {Solving for three-dimensional central potentials using matrix mechanics}
}
@article{article1,
author = {Jelic, V. and Marsiglio, F.},
year = {2012},
month = {09},
pages = {},
title = {The double-well potential in quantum mechanics: A simple, numerically exact formulation},
volume = {33},
journal = {European Journal of Physics},
doi = {10.1088/0143-0807/33/6/1651}
}
```

Comment: Frame titles will not be added to the table of contents use sections and subsections instead.

Comment: Why did you use \vspace{-5cm} in every frame?

Comment: Regarding numbered bibliography entries in a beamer bibliography: [How do I get numbered entries in a beamer bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124256/134144)

Comment: @leandriis actually if you see i have given command "\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}" which will give numeric, but during compilation it dosent give me the desire result

Comment: @leandriis i have used vspce in each slide because there was too much gap between the heading and the text. Is there better way?

Comment: Regarding the reference numnbers: Did you also inlcude `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}` as shown in the answer to the question I linked to in my previous comment?

Comment: Regarding the vertical alignment: By default text is vertically centered in a frame. Hence the white space between frame title and contents if your text only consists of a single line. I assume you want to top align the contents instead. Inserting a `\vspace` is not the best work-around for that as it causes problems with longer contents. To globally top align all contents of all frames, use `\documentclass[t]{beamer}`. (To locally change the alignment, use `\begin{frame}[t]`). See also [Positioning content at the top of a beamer slide (by default)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9889/134144)

Comment: For referencing i use this format- `\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}` and on next line i write `\addbibresource{references.bib}` and then at last i use `\printbibiliography` (which i have shown you in the code). Did you run my code. You might see the problem.

Comment: Since you did not include a bib file with the two entries that you cite in your presentation, I can not compile your file in order to see what output you get. Please prepare a complete [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) and include it in your question.

Comment: `\begin{frame}[t]` worked perfectly

Comment: @leandriis my bib file is there now. Hope you can help me now.

Comment: In order to replace the small  images in your list of references with the reference numbers, add `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}` to the preamble of your document.

Comment: Finally got it. Thank you so much. @leandriis due to present lockdown my university is helding a presentation day after tommorrow. Can you help me set up my mess so that i can look forward and start adding material as i am just stuck in making the adjustment. So if you dont mind if i edit my question and as told by jsbibra told me to do some changes for table of contents if you can help me out of it

Comment: @leandriis In the reference slide i made an frametitle and named as references but now two references are showing up. how to get rid of it as the template i am using i want references to come there

Comment: Please see my just added answer for a solution for the duplicate heading. I will add some more explanation later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes in comparison to your original code:

1. Numbers in list of references instead of small images: I added `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}` to the preamble. See also: [How do I get numbered entries in a beamer bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124271/134144)
2. Duplicate heading in the "References" slide: the `\printbibliography` command inserts its own "References" heading. If you also use the `\frametitle` command, you end up with two "References"  headings. To overcome this, use the `[heading=none]` option as in `\printbibliography[heading=none]`.
3. Add a table of contents: In order to get a table of contents, use `\section` and `\subsection` commands throughout your document. If every frame is in its own section, you might also want to add `\metroset{sectionpage=none}` in order to disable the section frames that are otherwise automatically inserted by the `metropolis` theme. In order to avoid repeating the section heading the the following `\frametitle` command, you can use `\secname` to access the name of the current section.
4. Vertical alignment: In order to top align the contents in all frames, add the `t` option as in `\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer}`. If you want to locally change the alignment, add the option to the `frame` environment as in `\begin{frame}[t]`. See also: [Positioning content at the top of a beamer slide (by default)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9890/134144)

Here is the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer} %<----- top align all frame contents
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=green,bg=blue}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{3pt}
\makeatother
\metroset{sectionpage=none} %<----- remove all section frames
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel} % <--- number references

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Symmetries in Classical Physics} % <---- add sections in order to get them listed in the table of contents
\begin{frame}{\secname} % <----- \secname here used the section's name as a frametitle
Hi\cite{Cosmic} Bye\cite{PeriodicPotential}
\end{frame}

\section{Translation Symmetry}
\begin{frame}{\secname}
\end{frame}

\section{Rotational Symmetry}
\begin{frame}{\secname}
\end{frame}

\section{Degeneracy}
\begin{frame}{\secname}
\end{frame}

\section{Parity}
\begin{frame}{\secname}
\end{frame}

\section{Time Reversal Symmetry}
\begin{frame}{\secname}
\end{frame}

\section{Symmetries in Dirac Equation}
\begin{frame}{\secname}
\end{frame}

\section{References}
\begin{frame}{\secname}
    \printbibliography[heading=none] % <----- heading= none is added in order to prevent a duplicate heading
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Really Thank you for so much of patience and helping me out. I want a help in my starting page in my question i asked in my title page as there is a huge space in the title name and above and can it be more simplified as i tried doing `\large` command but it failed. And also for every line can i have those paragraph or line transparent which would look good as i tried using the `setbeamercovered{transparent}` but had alot of error.(i Know i am being too selfish and asking favors like this please forgive me as i am done with the decoration and add my material.

Comment: Would love if you can add your email id so that i dosent make a mess here in this platform.

Comment: @AnshulSharma: Please ask a new question specifially about the alignment in your titlepage. Regarding: "And also for every line can i have those paragraph or line transparent which would look good": I don't understand what exactly this refers to. As this is also appears unrelated to bibliography or table of contents, please also ask a new question sepcifially focussing on this.

Comment: here is the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554437/title-page-alignment-and-transparenting-paragraph-and-lines-in-beamer . I asked an another question. Sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add sections as below--

The picture added is for the background and can be changed as per choice

All code taken from -- [Table of contents in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68714/table-of-contents-in-)
beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{%
        \tikz\node[opacity=0.3] at (current page.center) 
         {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image}};}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{}
    \section{Test Section One}
    \begin{frame}
        Contents of section one
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Test Section Two}
    \begin{frame}
        Contents of section two
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Test Section Three}
    \begin{frame}
        Contents of section three
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir i tried again and it worked but its creating a new whole slide again, i.e. it is making an another duplicate slide by using section command and in the table con content slide, there is a huge gap between two section titles as i am using different template and you too also sir. It Would be beneficial if you use my code and template and see the probelm.